# How to access my json data in my case - swift

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I have the following son String which is sent to me via a web service.  I am trying to access my dictionary within it and I am getting errors.  Please can someone advise?

My json String:

```
 {"status":200,"message":"Registration success","firstname":"tommy","lastname":"tang","userId":17,"email":"t@gm.com"}
```

My code for trying to access 'status'

```
          do{
                let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
                print("jsonObject: \(jsonObject)")

                guard
                    let regArray = jsonObject as? [[String:String]] else{

                        print("json messed up")
                }

                guard
                    let status = regArray["status"] as? String else{
                        print("error")
                }
                print("status: \(status)")

            }catch let error{
                print("print error: \(error)")
            }

        }else if let requestError = error{
            print("error detail: \(requestError)")
        }else{
            print("unexpected error")
        }
```

The error that I am getting is 'cannot subscript a value of type [[String:String]] with an index of type String'

Even if I use

```
let regArray = jsonObject as? [[String:Any]]
```

I get the same error

Comment: you are creating array of dictionary while your data is in dictionary format. Create Dictionary<String, String>

Comment: That's simple: Your JSON is a Dictionary at top level (well, it's just a Dictionary at all). So `let jsonSerialized as? [String:Any]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserID and status is  Int. So it must be `[String : Any]`. And it is simple array of dict.

And in code, change

`status = regArray["status"] as? String`

to

`status = regArray["status"] as? Int`

because you assigning Int value as string so thats not possible.